# paraview-python: Could not import vtkCommonComputationalGeometry

Tags: python, ubuntu, paraview

I try to run a python script (test.py) containing this line only:

```
from paraview.simple import *
```

I want to use the last version of paraview. So, I downloaded it from the official webpage and I uncompressed the corresponding archive into a folder, say /home/paraview.

If I do not anything more than running the script with

```
python test.py
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
from paraview.simple import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paraview'
```

So, I set my PYTHONPATH like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/paraview/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Then, I rerun my script and I get a different error message:

```
Error: Could not import vtkCommonComputationalGeometry
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/paraview/lib
```

where vtkCommonComputationalGeometry.so is but it does not work.

Furthermore, if I try to locate vtkCommonComputationalGeometry, I find it in another location:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry-6.2.so
```

I removed vtk with apt but it is still here.

Do you know how I could run my script?

Answer (score 2):

Just use pvpython, that can be found in ParaView binaries.

```
path/to/ParaView/bin/pvpython test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

try to install PVGeo package.

```
pip install PVGeo
```